# C++ Calling constructor inside another class constructor

Tags: c++

On this line `Transaction t(name, x, Date d(a, b, c));` this codes generates an error: `expected primary-expression before 'd'|`

Is it a valid code calling the constructor and passing another constructor call to it??!!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;
class Date{
private:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
public:
    Date(int a =0, int b=0, int c =0){
        this->a= a;
        this->b = b;
        this->c = c;
    }

    int getA(){
        return a;
    }

    int getB(){
        return b;
    }

    int getC(){
        return c;
    }

    void setA(int a){
        this->a = a;
    }

    void setB(int b){
        this->b = b;
    }

    void setC(int c){
        this->c = c;
    }

};

class Transaction {
private:
    char name[30];
    char x[10];
    Date *d;
public:



    Transaction(char const *name = "", char const *x = "", const Date *d = 0) {
        strcpy(this->name, name);
        strcpy(this->x, x);
//        this->d.setA(d.getA());
//        this->d.setB(d.getB());
//        this->d.setC(d.getC());
    }

    Date *getDate() {
        return d;
    }

};

int main() {

    int a,b,c;
    char name[30];
    char x[10];

    a=1;
    b=2;
    c=3;

    cin>>name;
    cin>>x;

    Transaction t(name, x, Date d(a, b, c));

}
```

Comment: I have to ask. What's the point of NOT using strings in C++?

Comment: it should be just `Date(a, b, c)`

Comment: Sure, just don't try to name it, i.e. `Date(a,b,c)`.

Comment: Please note that `Date` and `Date*` are two different things. You should avoid the latter.

Comment: None of the above. You have declared the constructor to accept a `Date *`, so you have to provide one. Probably what you meant is `new Date(a, b, c)`.

Comment: You shouldn't make us read an entire screenful of code for something that could be written in a 5-line [mcve].  Please reduce the code to the *minimum* that demonstrates the problem (hint: you wont need any `#include` lines).

Answer (score 3):

If you put `Date d(a, b, c)` on its own line, it defines an object named `d` of type `Date`. However, you can not have variable definitions as general expressions.

It is possible to create a temporary object of any type, using e.g. `Date(a, b, c)`.

But, and this is a big but, your `Transaction` constructor for some reason wants a *pointer* to a `Date` object, so you can't really create a temporary object and pass it. Instead you must define a variable, and pass it as a pointer to the `Transaction` constructor:

```
Date d(a, b, c);
Transaction t(name, x, &d);  // &d returns a pointer to d
```

---

Since the `Transaction` object wants a pointer to a `Date` object and stores the pointer itself, rather than copy into its own `Date` object, you must take care that the pointer you pass to the constructor stays valid until the `Transaction` object is destructed.

For something simple like this, I really suggest you consider passing the `Date` object by value, instead of as a pointer. And then change the member variable to be an object as well.

Also please consider you variable naming scheme. A good variable name shout be brief but descriptive. Take your `Date` member variables `a`, `b` and `c`, what do they mean? Will you understand what they are for if you come back to this code in half a year?

Comment: Thank YOU! It fixed my code!! I didn't know the Date() creating as temp inside the constructor!